# GROUP CONCAT and LEFT OUTER JOIN to split

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

I'm working with SQL Workbench. This is an example of the tables I have:

```
SITES
id

BUILDINGS
id
site_id

LEVELS
id
building_id
```

I have not created this DB and can't modify it. Each building corresponds to a site, so it contains a KEY to such site. Same with levels and buildings.

I am trying to get this result

```
site_id   |   buildings_id   |   levels_id
1         |   15, 16         |   (213, 214), (313, 314)
2         |   21, 22, 23     |   (350), (400, 401, 402), (501)
3         |   31, 32, 33, 34 |   (5001, 5002), (7001), (8009), (8400)
```

the first two columns are easy, but I'm having issues with the 3rd. The parenthesis are illustrative, I don't necessarily need those. But I need a way to split the string into levels by building_id.

Each (...) corresponds to the levels in one building.

This is the query I have working now which returns the first and second column. I have tried adding another LEFT OUTER JOIN to the query, but didn't work. I tried many things but most of the things I try return errors or weird outputs.

```
SELECT 
    sites.id AS site_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT buildings.id
        SEPARATOR '; ') AS buildings_id
FROM
    sites
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users_has_sites ON users_has_sites.sites_id = sites.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users ON users.id = users_has_sites.users_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    buildings ON buildings.sites_id = sites.id
WHERE
    users.id = 42
GROUP BY site_id;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any "hidden" reason that the desired result contains two separate rows for site_id 1 or just a typo??

Comment: Typo! Fixing it :)

Comment: can't see levels_id in your query..

Comment: because that's what I'm trying to achieve and everything I tried didn't work. I can show you what I tried but it's not going to be useful I think

Comment: One way is use `GROUP_CONCAT` two times. First you use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY site_id, buildings_id` then use that sub_table for `GROUP_CONCAT` with `site_id`

Comment: You need two `group_concat`s one over another

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I'm giving that a try again. I tried using two group_concat before but only got errors on the ide though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation: one by `building_id` and another by `site_id`.

> ```
> with b_l as (
>   select
>     b.id as building_id
>     , b.site_id
>     , concat('('
>       , group_concat(
>           l.id
>           order by l.id
>           separator ','
>         )
>       , ')'
>     ) as building_levels
>   from buildings as b
>     left join levels as l
>       on b.id = l.building_id
>   group by b.id, b.site_id
> )
> , s_b as (
>   select
>     s.id
>     , group_concat(
>         b_l.building_id
>         order by b_l.building_id
>         separator ','
>       ) as buildings
>     , group_concat(
>         b_l.building_levels
>         order by b_l.building_id
>         separator ','
>       ) as levels
>   from sites as s
>     left join b_l
>       on s.id = b_l.site_id
>   group by s.id
> )
> select *
> from s_b
> ```
>
> ```
> id | buildings | levels                 
> -: | :-------- | :----------------------
>  1 | 1,2,3     | (1,2),(3,4,5),(6)      
>  2 | 4,5,6     | (7,8),(9),(10,11)      
>  3 | 7,8,9     | (12,13,14),(15,16),(17)
>  4 | 10        | null
> ```

Or the same with lateral join:

> ```
> select
>   s.id
>   , group_concat(
>       b_l.building_id
>       order by b_l.building_id
>       separator ','
>     ) as buildings
>   , group_concat(
>       b_l.building_levels
>       order by b_l.building_id
>       separator ','
>     ) as levels
> from sites as s
>   left join lateral (
>     select
>       b.site_id
>       , b.id as building_id
>       , concat('('
>           , group_concat(
>               l.id
>               order by l.id
>               separator ','
>             )
>           , ')'
>         ) as building_levels
>     from buildings as b
>       left join levels as l
>         on b.id = l.building_id
>     group by b.id, b.site_id
>   ) b_l
>     on s.id = b_l.site_id
> group by s.id
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18207723d463231963439af0f8883a7d)*

Comment: Thank you mate for all that specially the fiddle. It makes sense to me now and I got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

according your require and table structure inference
you can try this sql

SELECT site.id,GROUP_CONCAT(c.building_id) building_id,GROUP_CONCAT(c.level_id) levels_id
from site, (
SELECT building.site_id,building.id building_id,
concat('(',GROUP_CONCAT(`level`.id),')') level_id
from building,`level` WHERE building.id = `level`.building_id GROUP BY building.id
) c where site.id = c.site_id
GROUP BY site.id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation, starting at the lowest level:

```
SELECT site_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(building_id ORDER BY building_id SEPARATOR ', ') as building_ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT('(', levels, ')' ORDER BY building_id SEPARATOR ', ') as levels
FROM (SELECT s.id AS site_id, b.id as building_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(l.id ORDER BY l.id SEPARATOR ', ') as levels
      FROM sites s LEFT JOIN
           users_has_sites uhs
           ON uhs.sites_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
           buildings b
           ON b.sites_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
           levels l
           ON l.building_id = b.id
      WHERE uhs.users_id = 42
      GROUP BY site_id, b.id
     ) sb
GROUP BY site_id;
```

Note that the `users` table is not needed because the id is in the junction table.  Also, `sites` is probably not needed but you are using it for a `LEFT JOIN` (although that is turned into an `INNER JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause).  I left it in, though.